# React hook form - Why textarea need to be wrapped by controller, not input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I am using React hook form for validation, and I found that native  element works well with just register

```
 <input
   {...register('Input', {
   validate: {maxLength: (value: string) => value.length >= 1,},})}
   placeholder="input"
   onPaste={e => replaceHttps(e)}
   />
```

But if I do the same for  , hook form simply didn't get the value of textarea, and I must use  from hook form to wrap it.

Does that imply textarea is treated as uncontrolled component while input is treated as controlled? I wonder the cause of that.

PS:The code below works.

```
 <Controller
                    name="TextArea"
                    control={control}
                    rules={{
                        required: true,
                        validate: {
                          maxLength: (value: string) => value.length >= 1,
                        },
                    }}
                    render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
                        <textarea
                            cols={90}
                            placeholder="Placeholder"
                            rows={4}
                            onChange={onChange}
                            value={value}
                        />
                    )}
                />
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. Do you mind updating [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-bardeen-d45rwg?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A347-355) to reflect the issue that you're seeing?

Comment: @moshyfawn Thanks for your effort. I have add a custom validation on textarea, and that's when it's not updating the data through onSubmit. Please check this sandbox. https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-http-jhz6m8?file=/src/App.tsx (It went well if I wrap it in a Controller though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [the reproduction codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-http-jhz6m8?file=/src/App.tsx) you've provided, it looks like you're using a slightly incorrect syntax to register your textarea element:

```
// instead of
<textarea
  {...(register("firstName"),
  {
    validate: {
      pattern: (value: string) => !/[!]/.test(value)
    }
  })}
/>
// register your element like this
<textarea
  {...register("firstName", {
    validate: {
      pattern: (value: string) => !/[!]/.test(value)
    }
  })}
/>
```

Here're [a working example codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-goodall-lxxggn)